# CSS anchor tag query

Tags: html, css, tags, anchor

I am using anchor tags with div id's assigned to them so the user is moved around the page.

Now my problem is when the user clicks the button, they are successfully transferred but I'm trying to make it so that `div` its brought to appears at the top of the page, not middle... you can see my progress and what i've tried by visiting the link i'm working on, all code is visible there.. you can see what I mean by clicking the home button.

http://eclipse-developers.com/v2/eclipse-developers.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no enough space at the bottom of the page. try adding some br at the bottom of the page.

Comment: if your answer is correct, i would suggest to use some height on a div instead of multiples br tags.

Comment: Please take a look now, it seems to go below the title for some reason, thanks for the help so far.